# Modeling qualified relations in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, class, language-agnostic, uml

I have a relational model where entities usually have relationships with two qualifiers, `start_date` and `end_date`, so to keep a history of past relationships.

When presented with the task of creating a data model with Hibernate, I faced the problem of dealing with these relationships that break the usual many-to-many relationship case. For instance let's say a `user` can have a certain access `permission` (which is in fact a real case), and we want to model the history of permissions a user has had:

```
| USER   |      | has_permission |      | PERMISSION |
|--------|      |----------------|      |------------|
| userId |------|userId          |------|permissionId| 
| user   |      |permissionId    |      |permission  |
----------      |start_date      |      -------------
                |end_date        |
                ------------------
```

Now how would you do this in a class model? What one would do in a regular case, creating a `User` class with a list of `Permissions` is no longer valid. Given that I have lots of entities, I don't want to end up with lots of "HasX" classes that only hold up another reference plus the startDate and the endDate.

Whats the common way to solve this problem?

I use Hibernate, but I guess the answer would be language-agnostic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you want to maintain the history of a many-to-many *association* (or *relationship type*), such as `hasPermission`, you have to turn it into a class, such as `PermissionByUser`, with attributes for the time interval that defines the valid-time of a specific *link* (or *relationship*), such as MichelReap-hasPermission-DeleteUser. So, you get a model like the following:

[image]

Replacing a many-to-many association with a class and two many-to-one associations is a well-known pattern (see, for instance, chapter 5 of [my tutorial](https://oxygen.informatik.tu-cottbus.de/IT/JsFrontendApp/tutorial.html)) . Notice that the "dots" at the `User` side and at the `Permission` side denote corresponding reference properties (`user`and `permission`) to be added to the `PermissionByUser` class.